# i want all comments for each post using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter, forum

Image shows all of my posts where i want to show all comments for each post.i marked the comments section with the red color.`

```
public function forum(){
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('tourism_con/forum');  
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('forum_posts')->num_rows();
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['per_page'] = 5; 
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination pagination-lg'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $data['forum_title']='Forum :: Home Page';
    $data['forumPosts']='forumPosts';
    $data['forum_details']=  $this->tourism_model->get_forum_post($config);
    $data['comment_count']=$this->tourism_model->get_comments_by_post();
    $this->load->view('Forum/forum_home',$data);
}
```

The above code is controller part. 
and the following code for model to retrieve all posts from database.

```
public function get_forum_post($config){
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->db->order_by("post_id", "desc");
    $query =   $this->db->get('forum_posts',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));  
    return $query->result();
}
```

the following code for comments in model to retrieve comment from database

```
public function get_comments_by_post(){
   $this->db->select('comment_id');
   $this->db->distinct();
   $this->db->from('comment');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->num_rows();
}
```

the view code part

```html
<div class='container forumBG'>
   <?php 
     foreach ($forum_details as $forum_post_details) {
    ?>
    <div class="row">
   <div class="forumPosts col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1 ">
     <h3 autofocus='autofocus'><strong > <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>tourism_con/full_post_details/?post_id=<?php echo $forum_post_details->post_id?>"> <?php echo $forum_post_details->topic_title?></a></strong></h3>
        Written By:<strong><?php echo $forum_post_details->user_name?></strong><br/>
      Posted on <strong><?php echo $forum_post_details->written_time?></strong>
      <p><?php echo substr($forum_post_details->description,0,105) ;?> ...</p>
   </div>
     <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-0 forumComment">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12 forumCommentSub">
    <i class="fa fa-comments fa-1x"> <?php echo $comment_count;?></i>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 forumCommentSub">
      <i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"> <?php echo $forum_post_details->post_views?></i>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
 <?php }?>
```

the above code problem is it retrieves all comments from database.i don't want it.i want all comments for each post.how to write the query to retrieve data for each post.

Comment: Then select your comments using the `post_id` as the criteria

Comment: all posts together retrieve from database.how i could separate the post_id from those posts?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing yoou database structure

Comment: Post table and comment table those are two different tables.so whenever i need data i just applied query on both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Do this: past `post_id` in `get_comments_by_post` function

```
public function get_comments_by_post($postid){
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $postid");
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result_array();
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work.it shows                                                                           A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: models/tourism_model.php

LineNumber:144                                                                                        $all_posts[$i]['comment'] = $this->get_comments_by_post($all_posts[$i]['post_id']);

Comment: $data['forum_details']= $this->tourism_model->get_forum_post($config);                                         In $data['forum_details'] where the all posts information is stored.now you just tell me how could i separate the post_id from the array.then i will send the post_id to model and it will sends back total number of comment for each post.

Comment: @hmamun can you please post what comes in `$data['forum_details']`?

Comment: post in question, i will tell you how to retrieve `post_id`